#  Shipping Methods are not working in magento 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I activated flat shipping in the shipping options and whenever you do checkout  it says `“Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.”`Any one please help me since i am a beginner in magento.

**EDIT**

I have tried  other shipping methods too its also showing the same. we have upgraded Magento ver. 1.4.1.1 to magento 1.7. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

**EDIT 2**
[image: Folder structure in version 1.4]

After upgrading community folder contains only `Phoenix` folder. After that i added `Biebersdorf`folder  by seeing an error in checkout page. I don't the the purpose of folders `AW` and `RocketWeb`. Since i am not familiar with magento. 
If the image is not visible  i have added the image in this url

***http://i47.tinypic.com/14smix1.jpg***

Comment: You didnt enter a price for the flat rate shipping...

Comment: @Gershon Herczeg  i have added price still its not working

Comment: so? no sales at all? none of the shipping methods are working?

Comment: @ivantedja  yes none of the shipping methods are working

Comment: @ivantedja client is saying it was working fine before upgrading.. Checkout was disabled while upgrading. we have downloaded files through FTP and upgraded it in local host then uploaded it through FTP. I think the problem may be missing of files while downloading or uploading or upgrading.

Comment: @LimiJerin yup pretty sure it is caused by upgrading, 1.4 to 1.7 has pretty much changes, looks like some modules in your community / local folder is not compatible, can you list it?

Comment: @ivantedja i have updated my question. Please check it out and give me a suggestion.

Comment: Have you installed any other module which is overriding OnepageController.php ?
Or you have installed any module that causing conflict-ions ?
Please check it as well.

Comment: @Ankur Srivastava i disabled `onepage checkout` and tried `Checkout with Multiple Addresses` it also showing `Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do you have any Checkout files modified on your project? Or maybe custom checkout.
I will list the code locations you need to check to make sure your Shipping works correctly.

So to begin with: Magento has very special work process with Shipping rates - it's called "collectRates" and is some modification of pattern "composite".

To make sure that everything works correctly on the code basis you need to first check the Onepage.php model (app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php): lines 330, 341, 556, 616; There should be code

`{address}->setCollectShippingRates(true)`

where {address} is current address variable.

This code is significant for future "collectRates" processes, because just when the Onepage Checkout page is initializing the "collectRates" process has already been processed, and the flag "collect_shipping_rates" is set to "false". If it's not set back to true, the next "collectRates" process will not be performed.

After you check the location above, and it still doesn't work - you might want to add some logging to Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available::getShippingRates method. If method is properly executed and return some rates from $this->getAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates() call, there might be some issues with .phtml template on your locan theme (default path to .phtml is app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml).

Here's how you can log the outcome from `$this->getAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates()` call (`Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available::getShippingRates` method):

```
$groups = $this->getAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
$printGroupes = array();
    foreach ($groups as $code => $groupItems) {
        foreach ($groupItems as $item) {
            $printGroupes[$code][] = $item->getData();
        }
    }
Mage::log($printGroupes, null,'special.log');
```

Please note, that the result array with all rates will be logged into "special.log" under var/logs folder.

I wish I could be more of help, but the issue requires some digging into code, the debugger will be even more helpful than logging, if you can get hold of one.

Cheers!

Comment: i think Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available::getShippingRates method  returns NULL value. Can i echo inside `Available.php`. if i give `echo or print_r()` its simply loading. doesn't print anything not even `Array()`

Comment: If the Magento logging is turned on, you can try to log the results in custom log: `Mage::log($this->getAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates(), null, 'custom.log')`

Comment: i disabled `onepage checkout` and tried `Checkout with Multiple Addresses` it also showing `Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time`

Comment: Since i am new to magento i don't know how to turn on logging.Where should i add this code? in available.php? and where should i find the file custom.log.

Comment: i found log settings in config->Developer->log settings its already enabled and `System Log File Name` is `system.log ` and `Exceptions Log File Name` is `exception.log`but i couldn't find such files inside `{{base_dir}}/var/log`

Comment: i have enabled logging in my localhost, when i give a simple code like this `Mage::log('My log entry');` it writes into the log file.But when i give a variable like `$group` or `Mage::log($this->getAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates(), null, 'custom.log') ` its simply loading. sometimes it shows a blank page.  In server both are not writting.

Comment: Hi Limi, I'm sorry for misleading you a bit. You see, the array that you get from $this->getAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates() contains nested objects, that's why it's probably too big and just ends up eating all of the allowed memory and dying. You should instead add next code to remove nested objects:`$printGroupes = array();foreach ($groups as $code => $groupItems) {foreach ($groupItems as $item) {$printGroupes[$code][] = $item->getData();
                }
            }Mage::log($printGroupes, null,'special.log');` Also notice, that the outcome will be written in **special.log** file

Comment: Actually, I will update my post, so the code is easier to read.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16573/discussion-between-limi-jerin-and-slayer-birden)

Comment: Now the problem has been solved. Problem was inside the function `getCarrierByCode`. Thank you so much for your help. And i am awarding the bounty mark to you...

Answer (score 1):

Price should be entered for Flat Rate shipping to work

The problem might be of the country selection

Ship to applicable countries is set to "Specific Country" and you selected "Canada".

So you will see this shipping method only if you select Canada on the frontend during the checkout.

Or

You can make this to All Countries and check whether its working or not.

Comment: i have added price and changed countries to `All Countries` still its not working. i have added new screenshot.

Comment: Is there any template used on the front-end or some condition that is restricting the flat rate to be applied applied, Check this by enabling any other shipping method and if you still face such problem then if you can create a new Admin user and provide me if possible so that I can check what exactly the problem is

Comment: I checked by enabling other shipping method its still showing  `Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.`

Comment: since its a live site of my client i cannot give login details.Can you list out the possible reasons so that i can check it out